# Apply a user-defined function to one df, using a single column in another df

Tags: r, dictionary, apply, tidyverse, tidytext

df1 (1,500 rows) shows questions, percent correctly answered, and count of question attempts:

```
qtitle                                   avg_correct                       attempts  

"Asthma and exercise, question 1"         54.32                            893
"COVID-19 and ventilators, q 3"           23.60                            143
"Pedestrian vs. car MVCs"                 74.19                            227
"Hemophilia and monoclonal Abs"           34.56                            78
"COVID-19 and droplets"                   83.21                            234
```

Using the tidytext library, the most frequent words in the qtitle column were identified and counted by frequency to create a second dataframe (df2, with 320 rows).

```
word                n
COVID-19            68
Trauma              57
Hemophilia          46
```

I would like to use each entry in the word col of df2 to match with words in the question titles  in df1 (qtitle) and find the mean of avg_correct, sum of attempts, and include frequency of the search term (n in df2).[ie., map df2 onto df1 via user-defined function]

```
word            avg_correct        attempts              count(n)
COVID-19        55.23              456                   68
Hemophilia      45.92              123                   46
```

This doesn't work (obviously)

```
correct_by_terms <- function(x) {
  filter(df1, str_detect(title, x))
  result <- summarise(df1, mean = mean(average), n = n(), x = x)
  return (result)
}
frequent_terms_by_correct_percent<- map_df(df2$word, correct_by_terms)
```

Comment: Seems this might do better with a `fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this base R approach. Using `sapply` we loop over each `word` in `df2`, match it with `grepl` in question title in `df1`, and return the `mean` of `avg_correct` and `sum` of `attempts` for those indices.

```
cbind(df2, t(sapply(df2$word, function(x) {
        inds <- grepl(paste0('\\b', x, '\\b'), df1$qtitle)
        c(avg_correct = mean(df1$avg_correct[inds]), 
          attempts = sum(df1$attempts[inds]))
})))
```

Comment: You cannot simply average the avg_correct.  Consider avg_correct value of 50 based off 2 attempts and another avg_correct of 98 based off 100 attempts which yields a mean(avg_correct) of 75, but taking into account the number of attempts gives an average of 99.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something using base R to calculate what you are asking for.

```
# get total number of correct per question
df1$correct <- df1$avg_correct * df1$attempts / 100

# initialize attempts and correct to 0
df2$attempts <- 0
df2$correct <- 0

# loop over df2
for (df2_index in 1:nrow(df2)){
  df2_row <- df2[df2_index,]
  # loop over df1
  for (df1_index in 1:nrow(df1)){
    df1_row <- df1[df1_index,]
    # if df1 qtitle contains df2 word
    if(grepl(df2_row$word, df1_row$qtitle, fixed = T)){
      df2[df2_index ,"attempts"] <- df2[df2_index ,"attempts"] + df1_row$attempts
      df2[df2_index ,"correct"] <- df2[df2_index ,"correct"] + df1_row$correct
    }
  }
}

df2$avg_correct = (df2$correct / df2$attempts) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If the words you are looking to match up are all **words** that can identified through tokenization like the examples you showed, I would:

- tokenize,
- inner join, then
- `group_by()` and summarize.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df1 <- tribble(~qtitle,                                ~avg_correct,   ~attempts,  
               "Asthma and exercise, question 1",      54.32,          893,
               "COVID19 and ventilators, q 3",        23.60,          143,
               "Pedestrian vs. car MVCs",              74.19,          227,
               "Hemophilia and monoclonal Abs",        34.56,          78,
               "COVID19 and droplets",                83.21,          234
)

df2 <- tribble(~word,              ~n,
               "COVID19",         68,
               "Trauma",           57,
               "Hemophilia",       46) %>%
  mutate(word = tolower(word))

df1 %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, qtitle) %>%
  inner_join(df2) %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  summarise(avg_correct = mean(avg_correct),
            attempts = sum(attempts),
            n = first(n))
#> Joining, by = "word"
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   word       avg_correct attempts     n
#>   <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 covid19           53.4      377    68
#> 2 hemophilia        34.6       78    46
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>